# error while removing extra values using regex in nifi

Tags: regex

i am a sample data as below

```
{
 CALLING_NBR = 1, / * nn svjfv ks;am scjv * /
 CALLED_NBR = 2, / * ssvdsv * / 
 EVENT_BEGIN_TIME = 3, / * * / 
 DURATION = 4, / * dhuf bvhsbv sjkncjsv jsvnjsdbv 
  the value of rthe vbisu * / 
 BILLING_PREFIX = 5 ,
 CALLING_CIRCLE_TYPE_ID = 6,

 CALL_TYPE = 7, / * call type* / 
CALLING_PREFIX = 8, / * calling e * /
```

}

now using regex equation i need to remove all the data in between this `/* */` 
sample output:-

```
    {
     CALLING_NBR = 1, 
     CALLED_NBR = 2, 
     EVENT_BEGIN_TIME = 3, 
     DURATION = 4,
     BILLING_PREFIX = 5,
     CALLING_CIRCLE_TYPE_ID = 6,
     CALL_TYPE = 7,
    CALLING_PREFIX = 8, 
   }
```

I have used this regex but no use :

Regex: `(/ *)+(.*?)+(* /)*`
Replacement value: `$1`

Comment: Use ``\s*/ \*[^*]*(?:\*(?! /)[^*]*)*\* /``, see https://regex101.com/r/gslKXr/1, replace with an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example data, you could match what you want to remove and then replace with an empty string instead:

```
(?s)/ *\*.*?\* */
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7huUif/2)

Or match 0+ times a horizontal whitespace char `\h` instead of a space only:

```
(?s)/\h*\*.*?\*\h*/
```

- `(?s)` Dot all mode, make the dot match a newline
- `/\h*\*` Match `/`, 0+ times a horizontal whitespace char and `*`
- `.*?` Match any char except a newline non greedy
- `\*\h*/` match `*`, 0+ times a horizontal whitespace and `/`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7huUif/1)